# Jquery UI dialog form button type change to submit

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have Ui dialog form with jquery and its convert Submit and cancel buttons which is [type="button'] both of them. I would like to change type of submit button to the "submit".

How can I do it? im failed all of my tries

This is js codes.

```
        $('#jui-dialog-form-horizontal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 700,
        buttons:

        {
            Submit: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

This is output to html.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can modify the button in the dialog to be `type="submit"` if you really choose, yet this may not give you the results you are expecting. It would be better to add to your button callback to select the form and trigger the `submit` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#jui-dialog-form-horizontal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 700,
    buttons: {
      Submit: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $("#jui-form").submit();
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });

  $("#jui-form-save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#jui-dialog-form-horizontal').dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="jui-form">
  <label>User Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <button type="submit" id="jui-form-save">Save</button>
</form>
<div id="jui-dialog-form-horizontal">
  <p>Are you sure you want to Submit this data?</p>
</div>
```

This example shows you how you can trigger the `submit` event on the form when the User clicks the Submit Button in the Dialog.